# FIREBASE: getting null while fetching the data from database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

> Attached is the firebase db structure screenshot.

[image]

> I want to get the data using node script. below is my code.

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("test/name");

console.log(ref)

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log("==========");
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

`console.log(snapshot.val());` always print **null**

Below is the result of  `console.log(ref)`

```
path: Path { pieces_: [ 'test', 'name' ], pieceNum_: 0 },
  queryParams_: QueryParams {
    limitSet_: false,
    startSet_: false,
    startNameSet_: false,
    endSet_: false,
    endNameSet_: false,
    limit_: 0,
    viewFrom_: '',
    indexStartValue_: null,
    indexStartName_: '',
    indexEndValue_: null,
    indexEndName_: '',
    index_: PriorityIndex {}
  },
```

What is the issue in the code?
referring this document:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using firestore but your code is for the realtime database, you need to change the code to the following:

```
var db = admin.firestore();
var ref = db.doc("test/name");

console.log(ref)

let getDoc = ref.get()
  .then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
      console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting document', err);
  });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data